# textbox only allow ip address in textbox c#

Tags: c#, textbox, ip

I'm trying to make a textbox only allow IP Addresses without validation using internet. I'm going to have a "private void textBox3_TextChanged" or a "timer1_Tick" which does the job. and each time I type or it ticks, it will check if it is a valid. That's why I want it to be fast, and only use a simple local code to check if it's valid, meaning 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255.

First, it should not do anything, but when an ip has been written, it will start a timer which then checks if the ip is reachable or not. The goal of this, is that when the IP has been written, a picturebox will turn red if ip is not reachable after about 4 secounds, and if it's reachable, it will turn green, then stop till "textbox3_TextChanged"

I tried something like ping, but it crashed if nothing was typed and it lagged if ip was not reachable:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();

        options.DontFragment = false;


        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        string data = "ping";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 120;
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(textBox3.Text, timeout, buffer, options);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        }
        else
            pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF7LK.jpg

Please help :)

Comment: may be you should wait for the user to input the entire ip, then check for format validity and for reachability. This would avoid the crashing. The lagging is the usual way how the ping method finds out that the ip is not reachable.

Comment: you could use the `KeyDown` event of the `textBox` and check there whether ENTER has been pressed and then do your checks

Comment: just put all code inside try catch block

Comment: I think the best practice would be to check the ip address after user presses enter or clicks button. That way you can overcome many problems already.

Comment: The IP address has 1 to 3 digit sections separated by period, thus you can write a method to check if entire sections are valid and send ping command immediately. If an exception occurs, catch block should handle and display "destination IP unreachable" error.

Comment: yes, I thought about doing that, but was a bit unsure to put it all in one piece. Tetsuya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace `textbox3_TextChanged` by something like this :

(For this example my interface got one TextBox called `textBox` and one TextBlock called `textBlock`)

```
//async to not freeze the UI
private async void TextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;

    //a little regex to check if the texbox contains a valid ip adress (ipv4 only).
    //This way you limit the number of useless calls to ping.
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$");
    if (rgx.IsMatch(tb.Text))
    {
        int timeout = 120;
        try
        {
            var reply = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(tb.Text, timeout);
            textBlock.Text = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success ? "OK" : "KO";
        }          
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is TimeoutException || ex is PingException)
        {
            textBlock.Text = "KO";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (textBlock != null)
        {
            textBlock.Text = "Not valid ip";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are meaning by using TextBlock. It's not in the toolbox and it's not in the events. Please Specify.

Comment: I meant you are using a picture box in your code, so you can replace my textblock by your picture box. f.e: `textBlock.Text = "KO";` -> `pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.Red;`

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void TxtEthStaticIP_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b");
            Match match = regex.Match(TxtEthStaticIP.Text);
            if (match.Success == false)
            {
                TxtEthStaticIP.Text = approvedethernetip;
            }
            else
            {
                approvedethernetip = TxtEthStaticIP.Text;
            }
        }
```

This is another idea of having a TextBox works like this. You have to declare an approved string for default text and this might help some situations who look like this.

An even better solution could be Validation and Validated events of the TextBox